# Can an executable be linked to a dynamic library after its built?

Tags: macos, binaryfiles, dynamic-linking

I have built a binary 'foo'. I now want the executable to be a linked to a dynamic library 'bar'. How can I link foo to bar?(using `ld` or any other way). I don't want to use `DYLIB_INSERT_PATH`on OSX or its equivalent `LD_PREOAD` on Linux.

I want to do this on OSX, but this question is a generic one.

Answer (score 0):

What's your intention?

The link process resolves symbols: it provide satisfactions to needs.

If the executable doesn't need any symbols offers by the dynamic library, the linker will entirely discard it.

You may replace a dynamic library by another one but you can't resolve a need when it doesn't exists.

Comment: For e.g. If I modify a reference to a function to use the version in the library I want to provide instead of a default library.