# Creating a dylib which gets linked at runtime

Tags: c, macos, dynamic-linking

I am trying to create a dynamic library which is meant to be linked and loaded into a host environment at runtime (e.g. similar to how class loading works in Java). As such, I want the dynamic library to be left with a few "dangling" references, which I expect it to pick up from its host environment when it is loaded into that environment.

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to create the dynamic library without explicitly linking it to existing symbols. I am hoping to produce a dynamic library that does not depend on a specific host executable (or host library), rather one that is able to be loaded (e.g. by `dlopen`) in any host as long as the host makes a couple symbols available for use.

Right now, any linking command I've tried results in a complaint of missing symbols. I'd like it to allow symbols to be missing (ideally, just particularly specified symbols).

For example, here's a transcript with the error on OS X:

```
$ cat frotz.c 
void blort(void);

void run(void) {
    blort();
}

$ cc -c -o frotz.o frotz.c
$ cc -dynamiclib -o libfrotz.dylib frotz.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_blort", referenced from:
      _run in frotz.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I do the same thing using a GNU toolchain (on Linux), it helpfully tells me:

```
$ gcc -shared -o libfrotz.so frotz.o
/usr/bin/ld: frotz.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `blort'
can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

and indeed, adding `-fPIC` to the C compile command seems to fix the problem in that environment. However, it doesn't seem to have any effect in OS X.

All the other dynamic-linking questions I could find on SO seem to be about the more usual arrangement of libraries, where a library is being built to be linked into an executable before that executable runs, rather than the other way around. The closest related question I found was this:

- [Can an executable be linked to a dynamic library after its built?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789540)

which unfortunately has very little info, none of it relevant to the question I'm asking here.

---

UPDATE: I distilled the info from the answer along with everything else I'd figured
out, and put together this example:

- https://github.com/danfuzz/dl-example

Comment: How about using weak linkage? `__attribute__((weak))` or `__weak` or whatever at the syntactic level, then pass `-flat_namespace -undefined dynamic_lookup` to the linker.

Comment: I didn't know about the `-undefined` option at all. Just adding that seems to satisfy the OS X linker. And it looks like the GNU toolchain may use `ld -Ur` to mean the same thing. If you expand your comment into an answer, I'll certainly upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as my knowledge goes, you want to use **weak linkage:**

```
// mark function as weakly-linked
extern void foo() __attribute__((weak));

// inform the linker about that too
clang -dynamiclib -o bar.dylib bar.o -flat_namespace -undefined dynamic_lookup
```

If a weak function can be resolved at runtime, it will then be resolved. If it can't, it will be `NULL`, instead of generating a runtime (or, obviously, link-time) error.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info about weak linking. In my case, I am pretty sure I want it to turn into an error.

Comment: @danfuzz Then just 1. check for `NULL` and `abort()`, or just call the function pointer unchecked (in which case it will most probably segfault).